# Android - How to make height size of table row equals

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablelayout

I have created a table view using table layout and table row, and then i'm facing problem for height size, i want the height size is in equals size looks like standard table. i create it with TableRow dynamically, here is my code :

TableLayout xml.

```
<android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hv_cust_prop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="1" />

</android.widget.HorizontalScrollView>
```

TableRow item xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_header_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:text="Header 1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Generating row Java.

```
row = new TableRow(getActivity());
                        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
                        lp.gravity = Gravity.FILL;
                        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        View head = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.item_cell_cust_prop, null);

                        FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) head.findViewById(R.id.container_header);
                        container.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_bg);

                        TextView txtHeader = (TextView) head.findViewById(R.id.txt_header);
                        try {
                            txtHeader.setText(object.getString("CV_VALUE"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            txtHeader.setText("erorr");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        row.addView(head);
                        tableContent.addView(row);
```

with tableContent is TableLayout from previous xml.

[image: **And this is the result**]

I want any column height follows the largest height as same as column with wrapped text.

Any help will be appreciate.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

add single line true (this is depricated) or maxline 1 to textview as above

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:text="Header 1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

**Edit**

alternatively try to set  android:weightSum="1" to Linearlayout and set  android:layout_weight="1" to FrameLayout like below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_header_bg"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="Header 1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: hi @Omi thank you, but i want my textview having maxwidth, so, it will be wrapped if text exceed the maimum width. :( 
but, thank for the answer. :)